# List index out of range even when I have bounded the value (python)

Tags: python, list, range

I have the following code and it works most of the time when I run it:

```
marvel_heroes = ['Wolverine','Spider-Man','Thor','Iron Man','Hulk','Captain America','Deadpool',
'Daredevil','Cyclops','Mr Fantastic','Professor X', 'Doctor Strange','Thing','Black Panther','Black Widow','Hawkeye','Vision','Shang-Chi', 'Ant-Man','Quicksilver','Star Lord',
'Rocket Raccoon','Drax','War Machine','Falcon']

marvel_heroes.append('Captain Marvel')
#print(marvel_heroes)

length = len(marvel_heroes)
print(length)
team = [marvel_heroes[random.randint(0, length)],marvel_heroes[random.randint(0, length)], marvel_heroes[random.randint(0, length)] ]


print('My team is:')
print(team)
print("\n")
```

Occasionally I get this error though:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 12, in <module>
    team = [marvel_heroes[random.randint(0, length)],marvel_heroes[random.randint(0, length)], marvel_heroes[random.randint(0, length)] ]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't really understand how it can be out of range when I have bounded it by the length variable, is this some sort of memory overflow issue or maybe a problem with having duplicate values sometimes?

Comment: It seems like you expect `randint(x, y)` to return a value _up to but not including_ y, but that is not the case.  y is included in the possible return values.

Answer (score 3):

The upper boundary of `random.randint` is *inclusive*, so you'd have to do

```py
random.randint(0, length - 1)
```

That being said, I'd recommend you use

```py
team  = random.sample(marvel_heroes, 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

The docs on [`randint()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) are clear:

> Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b. Alias for randrange(a, b+1).

Notice this includes the possibility that both `a` and `b` can be returned. So with a length of 5, `randint` can produce `5`, which will be out of bounds for zero indexed lists.`random.choices()` or `random.sample()` might be better functions for this.

```
team = random.sample(marvel_heroes, 3)
```

`choices()` will replicate your current behavior, but `sample()` will give you a random `unique` selection which seem like what you want.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html), `randint(a,b)` will return a value `x` so that `a <= x <= b` is true.

You could go for  `randrange()` instead to get `a <= x < b` instead.